# grub installation in fatal error in jbod disk setting

Tags: 12.04, grub2, raid

so i have this jbod drive, with two different partition

partition A is for windows while B i would like to have ubuntu 12.04 in it

however at the end of ubuntu installation, there is an error stating grub failed to install and a fatal error.

i was given option as to where to install the grub, and i tried them all and all giving me the same fatal error

here is one example of options given

/dev/mapper/nvidia_eeffaace1

to my knowledge grub is supposed to be installed in /dev/sda but in jbod configuration, both sda and sdb isnt available

please help me and thank you

Comment: I have the same exact issue. Did you find a fix for this? I have the same exact options for the grub install that you do.
Thanks, Andy

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but i noticed something interesting when playing around with my Ubuntu Server install.

If you run from a normal 12.04 live cd and run Gparted (`sudo gparted` from the terminal) you may see the same... With larger arrays and UEFI you need a GPT as everyone has figured out by now. But here is the gotcha... (at least for me)

Once you declare the table (Device > Create Partition Table... Click on Advanced and select "gpt"), try creating a partition. Odds are if you are having trouble it will not be `/dev/sdaX`. It will be `dev/mapper/yaddayaddayadda` or something similar. Try typing that in for your grub installation.

mine was `/dev/mapper/isw_deccijgjej_Raid1p1`